# Is 'donation' considered as commerical?

Tags: iphone, licensing

I want to port an open source program to iPhone, the license prohibited any commercial use of the code. I emailed the author and he sent back an email saying freeware is ok.

Of course I cannot (should not) charge anything on top of the code. Still, I want to get compensation for my work on UI design, graphics and integration work.

So I wonder:

1. Is donation (via PayPal) OK for my case?
2. Is in-app purchase OK? i.e. the program is free, the user has the option to buy addition theme graphics?

Thanks

EDIT:

Let me modify this to a hypothetical question. What if:

- some course code is found on the net
- there is a license coming with it, stating freeware is ok
- the author cannot be contacted

Then

- someone compiles and ports the code  to a new platform
- and adds some graphics
- any necessary code changes are published
- *in* the program, a donation link is added
- *in* the program, (iPhone version), an in-app purchase option is added

Any comments on the above scenario?

Comment: Not sure I agree with the 'off-topic' close votes, guys. Licensing issues are very much "of interest to other programmers" as per the FAQ.

Comment: @paxdiablo - In general, I think that people regard licensing and compensation questions as off-topic because we're programmers, not lawyers, and it's hard for us to give definitive answers to the questions.

Comment: I don't know much about women either but it doesn't stop me spewing forth my opinions on the matter :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you asking us? We don't have the copyright and we cannot license it to you.

You've already been in contact with the creator, these questions are better suited for him.

Personally, I would think both your scenarios are okay since no-one is *forced* to pay you for the use. But, as I said, I'm not the copyright holder. You need to either have a lawyer look over the licence or get a very explicit release from the author stating that what you want to do is okay.

---

Okay, based on your edit.

Here is what my employer would most likely do (a company *deadly* serious about IP issues).

They would evaluate the relative costs of getting into trouble misusing the program (getting their considerable legal department to evaluate the licence) against that of just clean-rooming the program. They would choose the cheaper option and go with that.

Now here's what *I* would do, not having my own personal Nazgul of lawyers.

If I couldn't contact the author, then he's probably a one-man show - he'll be able to afford legal representation about as well as I can so will be unlikely to push that hard, in a legal sense.

I would argue that my application is *indeed* freeware since I'm not charging anything for its use. If a customer chooses to ask for extras (in-app purchase) or make a donation, that money transfer is not tied to the acquisition of my freeware at all.

Of course, if your freeware is near-useless without an in-app purchase, it could be argued that the connection *is* there between money and product transfers.

But I think I would be quite safe going the donation route. There is an absolute unbundling of the two events (product transfer and money transfer) there and one does not require the other.

Some people have even just asked for donations *without* a reciprocal arrangement ([Save Karyn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Save_Karyn)), although *I* wouldn't give money to some clown who'd already proven themselves inept at managing it.

Standard disclaimers apply: I am not a lawyer, I am not *your* lawyer, I don't even look like a lawyer from a hundred yards away.

Comment: I am contacting the author for this specific question. In the meanwhile, please consider the question in a hypothetical situation as in the EDIT section ...

Answer (score 1):

Note that [open source](http://opensource.org/docs/osd) licenses allow commercial use and distribution (see #5 and #6 of linked page).  So this is *not* open source, and whether your scenarios are allowed depends on the actual license.

Comment: That's for commercial _use_, not commercial _distribution_. I should point out that it doesn't invalidate your answer though.

Comment: @paxdialbo: doesn't matter, it's all the same.

Comment: An "open source" license can absolutely put restrictions on use and distribution. The term for open source software with a license which does not do this is "free software" (free as in freedom). Most open source software is also free software, but it does not have to be. And not all software that calls itself "open source" conforms to the OSD that you linked. You have to read the actual terms of the license.

Comment: @hasen, with respect, that's not right. Use and distribution are not the same thing. I can use Linux as much as I want, make whatever changes I want and keep those changes locked up away from the world forever. But, the second I distribute that code, I have to release it under the GPL. The link given specifically states "The _distribution_ terms of open-source software must comply with ...".

Comment: @Tyler, I never said there were *no* restrictions (free software licenses have restrictions too).  I also didn't say anything about software that "calls itself open source".  I can call myself the Queen of Sheba, that doesn't mean I am.  I also said it depended on the license.

Comment: @pax, I thank hasen meant the OSD requires licenses to allow both commercial use and distribution.  If so, he's right.

Comment: I don't understand why "Open Source Initiative inc." gets to claim all usages of the word "open source"... When I say "open source" I'm not saying "open source as defined by Open Source Initiative inc." but instead saying "the source is open"

Comment: @advs, the OSI coined the phrase (for software) over a decade ago.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I'm talking about term #6 of the OSI definition. If you put a restriction (whether it's regarding use or distribution) based on a field of endeavor, then it's not open source.

Comment: @advs, [Voices from the Open Source Revolution](http://oreilly.com/catalog/opensources/book/perens.html).

Comment: @advs89: I don't understand why an individual would think he can bend the meaning of a well-established term just because he doesn't like the official definition.

Comment: It's a common noun modified by a common adjective.  If it were made up of entirely new words then it wouldn't bother me so much.  But regardless, I think we're all (myself included) wasting far too much effort on semantics.

Answer (score 1):

How much are you compensating the author of the open source program for their work?

I am not sure whether donations would be considered "commercial" under the terms of the license, but from your description it doesn't really seem in the spirit of software you are porting.

And why are you asking us when you can just e-mail the author as you did before?

Comment: I am contacting the author for this specific question. The rationale behind this question is I see many great projects with source code out there and I think porting some of them to iPhone will be useful. To respect the original license, I will post the ported program as freeware. However, I am not sure a link to Paypal; or donation option (a click to AppStore in-app) is in conflict of the `freeware` concept.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the original author, he should have the canonical interpretation of his license.